# Flex 3 Customevent not getting dispatched

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a function called DrawPlaybook which listens to two events, one mouseclick event and one custom event.

```
public function DrawPlaybook(...):void
{
    //...... other stuff
    panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
        function(e:MouseEvent){onClickHandler(e,this.panel)});
    panel.addEventListener(CustomPageClickEvent.PANEL_CLICKED,
        onCustomPanelClicked);
}
```

I am planning to call the custom event from within "onClickHandler" like this:

```
public function onClickHandler(e:MouseEvent,panel):void
{
    var eventObj:CustomPageClickEvent = new CustomPageClickEvent("panelClicked");
    eventObj.panelClicked = panel;
    dispatchEvent(eventObj);
}

private function onCustomPanelClicked(e:CustomPageClickEvent):void {
    Alert.show("custom click");
}
```

And here is the class definition for CustomPageClickEvent:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.containers.Panel;

    public class CustomPageClickEvent extends Event
    {
        public var panelClicked:Panel; 

        // Define static constant.
        public static const PANEL_CLICKED:String = "panelClicked";

        public function CustomPageClickEvent(type:String){
            super(type);
            //panelClicked = panel;
        }

        // Override the inherited clone() method.
        override public function clone():Event {
            return new CustomPageClickEvent(type);
        }

        public function getPanelSource():Panel{
            return panelClicked;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that "onCustomPanelClicked" never gets invoked at all. Please let me know if you notice anything that I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have registered the event listener for `CustomPageClickEvent` on the Panel, but you're dispatching it from `DrawPlaybook`

Just change this:

```
var eventObj:CustomPageClickEvent = new CustomPageClickEvent("panelClicked");
eventObj.panelClicked = panel;
dispatchEvent(eventObj)
```

to this:

```
var eventObj:CustomPageClickEvent = new CustomPageClickEvent("panelClicked");
eventObj.panelClicked = panel;
panel.dispatchEvent(eventObj)
```

... or change the event listener to `this.addEventListener(CustomPageClickEvent.PANEL_CLICKED,
onCustomPanelClicked);`.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Changing the event listener to :

    this.addEventListener(CustomPageClickEvent.PANEL_CLICKED, onCustomPanelClicked);

works. Thanks a lot for your help.